# how do i convert a next button to a working submit button

Tags: jquery, forms, button, bootstrap-5

so I am trying to build a multiple step form with two tabs, tab has a user name, while tab two has the password, on page load, tab one is visible, if i click the next button, i m hide the tab1 and show tab2 with jquery, but when tab two show, i m finding it difficult converting the next button submit button to enable me submit the form.

tried this

```
$(function () {
    $('.tab1').show();

    $('#cracc').show();

    $('#nextBtn').on('click', () => {
        /* $('#nextBtn').html('Submit'); */
        $('.tab1').hide();
        $('#cracc').hide();
        $('.tab2').show(() => {
           $('.forgotPass').show(); 
           $('#nextBtn').html('Submit')
          
        })  
       
     })
        
        


   if (('.tab2').show()) {
        $('#nextBtn').attr('type', 'submit')
         $('#nextBtn').on('click', () => {
            $('form').submit(() => {
                alert('submitted')
            })
        })
   }

    

    
})
```

Comment: Do the same as you do with the tabs - render/include both buttons, then show/hide the one(s) you want as needed.  Depending on your HTML, you could have the buttons/show automatically via css with no need for an JS.

Comment: Alternatively, within `$('#nextBtn').on('click',` check which tab you're on

Comment: I recommend *against* changing the attributes.  It'll probably work, but the seems to be too much risk that it'll end up in the wrong state (eg if you add a back/reset button then don't add the reset code - though same can be said for a non-css (js) hide/show solution)

Comment: I second that. Way better would be to use two different buttons and change their visibility.

Comment: yah, i could use an alternative button, show/hide visibility, but as i believe that i should be possible to use one element while toggling between two attributes ie, the on tab1, the button should  be next, and on tab2 it should be a submit button, that actually works.

Comment: Problem is that your if statement is inside your "ready" function. so basicly you ask at the start if tab2 is show. After that you never check it again

Answer (score -1):

Here is a jQuery UI example.

```js
$(function() {
  function openTab(i) {
    // Conditionally trigger activation of a tab
    $("#showUser").html($("#user").val());
    if (i == 1) {
      if ($("#user").val() != "") {
        $("#tabs li").eq(i).find("a").click();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      $("#tabs li").eq(i).find("a").click();
    }
  }

  function submitForm(u, p) {
    // Submit Username and Password to a script via AJAX
    $.post("login.php", {
      user: u,
      password: p
    }, function(result) {
      if (result === "success") {
        window.location.href = "portal-entry.php"
      } else {
        openTab(0);
        $("#error").html(result.error);
      }
    })
  }

  $("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeActivate: function(e, ui) {
      // Prevent moving forward without filling in Username
      if ($("#user").val() == "") {
        $("#user").addClass("ui-state-error");
        return false;
      }
      $("#user").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
  });

  $("#nextBtn, #submitBtn").button();

  $("#nextBtn").click(function() {
    openTab(1);
  });

  $("#submitBtn").click(function() {
    submitForm($("#user").val(), $("#pass").val());
  })
});
```

```css
.ui-tabs div[id^='tabs-']>* {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#user, #pass, #showUser {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">User Name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Password</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="error">&nbsp;</div>
    <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="john@smith.com" class="ui-widget" />
    <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    User: <span id="showUser" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content"></span>
    <input type="password" id="pass" />
    <button id="submitBtn">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you can see how you can change the Tab with a Button click. This uses basic checks to confirm the User has entered some value in the text field.

This example uses AJAX instead of the traditional Form element.